# In Monster episode 5, why did Tenma tell the apartment lady that Mr. and Ms. Heinemann was fostering a child?

Tags: monster

In episode 5 of the *Monster* anime, when Dr. Tenma investigates Johan, and just before meeting the old blind man, he is talking with the apartment lady and asks her “So, Mr. and Ms. Heinemann who died, fostering a child”.

Does he mean Heinemann as in Eva Heinemann and her father, because they were also Heinemann?

Answer (score 3):

Neither. It was probably a mistake in the subs you were watching. She's referring to the Heinau (spelled Haynau in some translatios) couple. Johan stayed with them in a small flat in Munich from March '87 to April '88.

[image: chapter 10, pg 6]